# Docker-machine create: Error with pre-create check: "Hyper-v commands have to be run as an Administrator"

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I try to create a docker-machine with `docker for Windows 10` using next command:

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv default
```

But I get the next error

```
Error with pre-create check: "Hyper-v commands have to be run as an Administrator"
```

Anyone knows how to fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply start cmd (terminal) as admin.

Otherwise,
if this does not work: there is a known issue [#2989](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2989) in docker machine: the creation of a Docker machine fails with the error message "Hyper-v commands have to be run as an Administrator", even if your user is member of the Hyper-V Administrator group and the Hyper-V Administrators have full access to the folder containing the VM:

`λ Get-Acl E:\docker\ | Format-List
...
Access : BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrators Allow  FullControl`

[jtnord](https://github.com/jtnord) has found a workaround by creating a VM with fixed-size disk. He has tested this for users that are group members of Hyper-V Administrators and he has given FullControl for the base Folder for Hyper-V Administrators, as I understand it.

Answer (score 5):

**Just Add your current user to "Local Group": *'Hyper-V Administrators'*.**

Check your <*current username*> by:

```
> whoami
```

Start `cmd.exe` by **Administrator**:

1. Check *localgroup* by: `> net localgroup`
2. Add  to ***Hyper-V Admininstrators***: `> net localgroup "Hyper-V Administrators" <current username> /add`
3. **Sign out** or **Reboot**

Comment: This is a pretty method, I don't have to use cmd with administrator anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can change the properties on the docker-machine executable to Run As Administrator. The file is located (at least on my box) in C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-machine.exe Find this file, right click and select Compatibility and check the box "Run this program as an administrator".